# Почему controller в Angularjs не видит свою переменную?

Tags: angularjs

Есть такой пример на AngularJS, который вполне рабочий.

```js
const app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('testController', function($scope) {
  $scope.testScope = ['text-0', 'text-4', 'text-1'];
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<html ng-app="app">
<div ng-controller="testController">{{testScope}}</div>

</html>
```

Но если ее немного изменить

```js
const app = angular.module('app', []);
app.factory('myFactory', function() {
  return {
    import: (arr, text) => {
      arr.push(text);
    }

  }
});

app.controller('testController', function($scope, myFactory) {
  $scope.myFactory = myFactory;

  $scope.testScope = ['text-0', 'text-4', 'text-1'];

  myFactory.import(testScope, 'P-text');

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<html ng-app="app">
<div ng-controller="testController">{{testScope}}</div>

</html>
```

`controller` перестает видеть свою переменную...

Как с этим бороться и в чем причина?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все оказалось более чем просто

Не

> myFactory.import(testScope, 'P-text');

а

> myFactory.import($scope.testScope, 'P-text');

```js
const app = angular.module('app', []);
app.factory('myFactory', function() {
  return {
    import: (arr, text) => {
      arr.push(text);
    }

  }
});

app.controller('testController', function($scope, myFactory) {
  $scope.myFactory = myFactory;

  $scope.testScope = ['text-0', 'text-4', 'text-1'];

  myFactory.import($scope.testScope, 'P-text');

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<html ng-app="app">
<div ng-controller="testController">{{testScope}}</div>

</html>
```